# php preg_match_all multiple patterns

Tags: php, find, preg-match, design-patterns, preg-match-all

```
[-27439367, 160818667, 'http:\/\/cs13110.vk.me\/u109515688\/video\/l_97403fde.jpg', 'Super Bass', '', '0', 38674081, 37, 0, '2:34', '3', '_8cb245a336c2e35049', '']
```

Hello! Here is my sample text.... I need to use preg_match for multiple patterns... I need to find: 
1. -27439367 
2. 165375317 
3. http://cs6067.vk.me/u189929178/video/l_02613a05.jpg 
4. Super Bass 
5. 0 
6. 38674081 
7. 37 
8. 2:34 
9. 0 
10. 3 
11. _8cb245a336c2e35049

I used:

```
preg_match_all("/[(.*?), (.*?), '(.*?)', '(.*?)', '', '0', 0, 23, 0, '', '0', '(.*?)', '']/mis", $a, $hashtweet);
```

Comment: it looks like valid json, so http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: you can also explode, but it is json.

Comment: valid json would be double-quotes `"` not single-quotes `'` . i dont know if json_decode can handle that, if not str_replace helps

Comment: `print_r(json_decode(str_replace("'", '"', $string)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$json = "[-27439367, 160818667, 'http:\/\/cs13110.vk.me\/u109515688\/video\/l_97403fde.jpg', 'Super Bass', '', '0', 38674081, 37, 0, '2:34', '3', '_8cb245a336c2e35049', '']" ;
$json = preg_replace("/'/", '"', $json); //Replace single quotes by double quotes
$obj = json_decode($json);

var_dump($obj);

array (size=13)
  0 => int -27439367
  1 => int 160818667
  2 => string 'http://cs13110.vk.me/u109515688/video/l_97403fde.jpg' (length=52)
  3 => string 'Super Bass' (length=10)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => int 38674081
  7 => int 37
  8 => int 0
  9 => string '2:34' (length=4)
  10 => string '3' (length=1)
  11 => string '_8cb245a336c2e35049' (length=19)
  12 => string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe strip the `[]` brackets and do `explode(',', $input)` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php))?

Another idea: this looks like a valid JSON data, so `json_decode` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) should do the trick.